# Do multiple mysqli_queries use the same connection?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a mysqli_query statement like so:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query)
```

I am wondering:  If I call mysqli_query multiple times during the execution of a script, does it use the same connection to the db?  Or is a new connection established each time?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

It should use the same connection, providing you don't tell it to reconnect.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query()` (which is different from mysqli_query() but should behave the same in this regard) always uses the last opened connection if one isn't provided.

So for this:

```
$connection1 = mysqli_connect('host1');
$query1 = mysqli_query('SELECT column1');
$query2 = mysqli_query('SELECT column2');

$connection2 = mysqli_connect('host2');
$query3 = mysqli_query('SELECT column3');
```

`$query` and `$query2` will both run on the connection to host1, and `$query3` will run on the connection to host2

Comment: The `mysqli_query` function does not default to the last opened connect, like it's predecessor `mysql_query`. It **requires** the first parameter to be a link to an open mysqli connection, or it fails with an "invalid parameter count" error. - Check the manual entry. Note that the first version listed in the manual is the OOP version, which is not a function but an object method.